# How to chmod all files in sub-directories without chmod the folders?

Tags: linux, centos, debian, chmod

I have tried to chmod 444 for every HTML file in all sub-directories, but all files and folders were changed to 444 when I tried this command:

```
chmod -R 444 /home/ppp/ *.html
```

I just want to chmod all HTML files in /home/ppp folder and sub-folders, but not for folders and other file types.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: So sh script is not kind of programming?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this command :

```
find /home/ppp -type f -exec chmod 444 {} \;
```

Comment: I just want to chmod html only, so should I change it to "find /home/ppp -type *.html -exec chmod 444 {} \;"  ?

Comment: find /home/ppp -name "*.html" -exec chmod 444 {} \;

Comment: @SuperBerry Comment should be marked as accepted, I tested this and it worked like charm, thanks!